# How to debug .NET5 sources when you don't control the starting point sources

Tags: debugging, .net-core, visual-studio-debugging

So I have an interesting situation. I don't know how to debug my .net 5 code, because the starting point executable is not an executable I control. I am provided with a .NET5 DLL to which I can write plugins for. Because the process is dotnet.exe and my DLLs are not part of the starting point project, I cannot seem to get the visual studio debugger to actually debug anything I write.

I can attach to the dotnet process, but my breakpoints say they won't work because the symbols haven't been loaded for this project.

I have followed the miscrosoft documentation, but it only applies to a single "layer" of project, and doesn't seem to have any information about debugging a project that is a layer above the layer bring run by dotnet.exe.

I hope I described that well enough.

Comment: What debugger do you use to attach? Most debuggers won't load symbol files by default (or they cannot locate the symbol files for some reasons), but manually feed them with the symbol file (`dotnet build` can generate symbols by default or based on your project configuration), and then you can debug the code.

Comment: I agree with @LexLi, attach debugger to the process should be the only way to debug under this circumstance, so is your issue solved?